# Non US-ASCII characters dropped from full (profile) URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, unicode

I have characters which are outside 7-bit ASCII in my username, "Jakub Narębski". Characters outside US-ASCII are dropped from the full profile URL: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130454/jakub-narbski (observe that it is 'narbski', not 'nar**e**bski' or 'nar**ę**bski').

I'm not quite sure if it is a bug or not. I think that the last part of URL is purely informational; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130454 works as well, I suspect to allow to change one's name field.

---

***Added 2009-07-30:***
This feature request, in the form of stripping diacritical marks, got implemented ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)). Wouldn't it be a good idea to separate this [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) transliteration code and put it as [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) snippet or mini-library somewhere?

**See also:** [This Is America, Take Your Unicode Somewhere Else](http://teddziuba.com/2009/07/this-is-america-take-your-unic.html) blog post by Ted Dziuba, which mentions [Text::Unidecode](http://p3rl.org/Text::Unidecode) Perl module (which does US-ASCII transliterations of Unicode text), and mentions Stack Overflow in passing.

---

***Added 2009-08-30***
[Perl 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_6) has `:ignoreaccent` modifier, and there is also the [Text::Unaccent](http://p3rl.org/Text::Unaccent) Perl module (which uses [unac](http://home.gna.org/unac/description.en.html) C library).

Comment: The right way to do accent-insensitive comparisons is by comparing things at the primary strenth in the Unicode Collation Algorithm.  That is what it is there for.  You will never get them all otherwise.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's what we have in the substitution table

```
public static string RemapInternationalCharToAscii(char c)
{
    string s = c.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
    if ("àåáâäãåą".Contains(s))
    {
        return "a";
    }
    else if ("èéêëę".Contains(s))
    {
        return "e";
    }
    else if ("ìíîïı".Contains(s))
    {
        return "i";
    }
    else if ("òóôõöøőð".Contains(s))
    {
        return "o";
    }
    else if ("ùúûüŭů".Contains(s))
    {
        return "u";
    }
    else if ("çćčĉ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "c";
    }
    else if ("żźž".Contains(s))
    {
        return "z";
    }
    else if ("śşšŝ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "s";
    }
    else if ("ñń".Contains(s))
    {
        return "n";
    }
    else if ("ýÿ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "y";
    }
    else if ("ğĝ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "g";
    }
    else if (c == 'ř')
    {
        return "r";
    }
    else if (c == 'ł')
    {
        return "l";
    }
    else if (c == 'đ')
    {
        return "d";
    }
    else if (c == 'ß')
    {
        return "ss";
    }
    else if (c == 'Þ')
    {
        return "th";
    }
    else if (c == 'ĥ')
    {
        return "h";
    }
    else if (c == 'ĵ')
    {
        return "j";
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Updated a few times now; does this cover it?

Comment: Māori has ā.

There's also æ and œ (--> ae and oe) though I'm not sure if they turn up in names.

You could add Þ for when we get our first Anglo-Saxon users :-)

Comment: I also can't find the uppercase variants [L with stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_with_stroke) (`Ł`) and [D with stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_with_stroke) (`Đ`).

Comment: @John: There's @aether, which turns a single character to "ae" accoring to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38288/comment-notification-special-characters

Comment: @Jeff, why in the world are you hardcoding all those?  Use the Unicode Collation Algorithm and compare at the primary strength, which works even better than canonically decomposing and then removing Grapheme_Extend characters. The UCA1("ð") is the same as UCA1("d"), etc. Otherwise you fight a losing battle. Use the Unicode facilities; don’t hardcode stuff.

Comment: @tchrist this algorithm is quite fast, and it needs to be since it is potentially called hundreds of times per page. Do you have any c# source code examples?

Comment: @Jeff: Well, the UCA is supposed to be fast, too; there are big lookup tables, which may be a memory issue. But I don’t do C#; I'm not a Microsoft guy. I could have probably winged it in Java if you’d asked since I do Java stuff from time to time, but my primary language is Perl. I agree you’re doing better than the naïve stripping of Mark characters that I normally see done. It just seems painfully ad hoc, and we have tables for this stuff.

Comment: @Jeff: is there a reason you went with If-Else-If vs Switch? (did you test/compare?) posts here (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067/if-vs-switch-speed) and elsewhere (e.g. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx) indicate that switch is generally faster.

Comment: @faust kind of irrelevant for a number of reasons, the primary reason is that the sequence of if..then here is ordered by *frequency* that those letters occur in English. So it hits the most common cases first, and almost never goes all the way to the bottom.

Comment: @Jeff I've got a version using a unicode collation function in .net on this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/6740497#6740497 - I haven't measured the performance impact, but coverage is better, although I still need an exceptions table. I also delay load the hyphens which might be useful even if you prefer the hardcode lookup table for perf.

Comment: @dan great tip, I was looking for that code! I'll check it out.

Comment: @Jeff will be v. interested in any results if you benchmark it, especially as you have real data to work against. I'm pretty curious if the delay hyphen makes any diff for you by itself.

Comment: That doesn't work on my name. Please contain uppercase versions of that chars.(For example: Ç )

Comment: Using `ToLowerInvariant` might result in some strange behavior in character normalization, as `"İ".ToLowerInvariant()` gives us "İ" (Yes, the same character: Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE' (U+0130))

The issue seems to be related to yet another [Turkish Locale Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html) (love the article, btw.), and according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx#stringsinnet20_topic5) article, using `ToUpperInvariant` for string normalization is the recommended approach. What do you think?

Comment: I guess it's no use struggling: `"ı".ToUpperInvariant()` is `ı`

Comment: Please add support to Romanian diacritics: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214531/205508 Thank you! :-)

Comment: I see this problem persists:[my comment from three years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url?rq=1#comment221356_7696) still applies in full.

Comment: @tchrist, I've read some of your answers on Unicode here on StackOverflow, I doubt that many people have your recognition of that problem and fully grasp the concept of Unicode. Many just see it as "international ASCII" or a set of translation tables. The real solution would be using IRI's instead of URI's and not do any translation at all. C# even has that integrated.

Comment: I see a few problems with Icelandic.
'Ð' (uppercase) and 'ð' (lowercase) should be "d".
I see Þ (uppercase), but it's missing þ (lowercase) - should be "th"

Comment: My suggestion is to remove ð from òóôõöøő, and do this instead:
            else if ("ðđ".Contains(s))
            {
                return "d";
            }
            else if (s == "þ")
            {
                return "th";
            }

Answer (score 1):

The code above could be simplified and generalized by using unicode categories. Below method will also take into account also diacritics not explicitly mentioned above (e.g. in Czech there are also `řďť` which becomes `rdt`). It could be used as first step and then there could be manually replaced rest of the characters which are standard national characters but it is not good to have them in url.

Note: I have not measured performance of this solution.

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(string s)
{
    s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(s[i]) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) sb.Append(s[i]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

RemoveDiacritics("àåáâäãåąèéêëęìíîïıòóôõöøőðùúûüŭůçćčĉżźžśşšŝñńýÿğĝřłđßÞĥĵřďť");
                 "aaaaaaaaeeeeeiiiiıoooooøoðuuuuuucccczzzssssnnyyggrłđßÞhjrdt"
```

[Original code + comments how it works (Czech only)](http://www.aspnet.cz/Articles/92-jak-spolehlive-odstranit-v-net-z-retezce-diakritiku.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are often encoding in URLs, but it works just as well to drop them, too. That last part is purely informational (SEO ftw), so if you felt like it, you could even call yourself [Mary, Queen of Scots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130454/mary-queen-of-scots) and it still would go to the right page.

Comment: well, sort of. We realized that having lots of people link to a question as /12345/blah-foo-bar and /12345/baz-shell and /12345/extra-words was confusing Google in some cases, so we force-redirect to the 'correct' title now.