# @Peter works for Péter Török?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments, comment-replies

Not to single him out or anything, but just wondering if I can just do `@Peter` to address a reply to him, or if I have to copy and paste every time.

Comment: @Péter As easy as it is! No copy!

Comment: @Ladybug: I don't know how to get those magical letters by typing!

Comment: @poly - your keyboard is obviously faulty. My universal-French-keyboard-that-everyone-else-uses can type Péter Török without a problem.

Comment: @poly, hi :-) one receives notification of all comments to his/her posts/answers, rogardless of whom these were addressed to.

Comment: @peter - test for Jeff's fix

Comment: @Péter, test for the old behaviour...

Comment: @Arjan, thanks, this works still :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I *thought* this worked due to the AEther / aether thing but that must have been an anomaly.

So instead we now pass all @names to be matched through this function

```
rowname = HtmlUtilities.URLFriendly(rowname);
```

Which is documented here

[Non US-ASCII characters dropped from full (profile) URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696)

That should really fix this.

Comment: ironically this fix might break the aether/aether thing. :)

Comment: so, will "@Péter" still work?

Comment: @Kip, apparently it does - see @Arjan's comment above :-)

Comment: As an aside: so to reply to *Jörg* one could use *Jorg*, [but not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89051/joerg-works-for-jorg) *Joerg*.

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong suspicion that @Peter doesn't work.

At least I don't remember having been notified of any comment from you the day you posted this.

And my suspicion is now proven by the comments to the main post. Thanks @Gnoupi and @polygene :-)

Comment: only one way to be sure, post a comment on the question, and someone will put "@peter" comment after.

Comment: @Gnoupi, good idea, I will do it right away.

Comment: how about now? I just deployed meta only with the below fix.

Comment: @Jeff, I just got the notification of @Gnoupi's new comment to the main post, so I can verify that the fix is working.