# How are question title slugs generated so magically? (ß)

Tags: discussion, title, permalink, slug

I was just looking through some old posts and I noticed that a "ß" in a question title magically turns into an "ss" in the URL slug.

What function is being used to format the slugs? Clearly it has some advanced behavior in terms of determining character equivalents, rather than just ignoring special characters.

(Note: I just tried this with "ﬁ" and "ﬂ" and they're *not* converted to "fi" and "fl"...)

Comment: `String url = post.Title.Replace("ß", "ss");`

Comment: +1 Oh.. I see what you did there :P (ß)

Comment: [he co҉mè̑ͧ̌s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/319618)

Comment: @fredley: Okay... `String url = System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx.Replace(post.Title, "ß", "ss");` ... I might have those parameters reversed, though.

Comment: No way, unicode has ligatures?

Comment: @BenBrocka - Unicode has the full complement of crazy pony stripes.

Comment: @BenBrocka whenever I think about about ligature, diacritical, or digraph support in Unicode it makes me go [CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER UK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0478/index.htm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non US-ASCII characters dropped from full (profile) URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the current implementation is [still similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stackoverflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls/25486#25486) (although [Jeff mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#comment250677_7696) looking into [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6740497/366234))...

Taking 80 characters from the raw title, , `,`, `.`, `/`, `\`, and `_` are replaced with `-`, collapsing consecutive such characters into a single dash. Latin alphabetic characters are converted to lowercase, and the following substitutions are made:

```
àåáâäãåą => a
èéêëę    => e
ìíîïı    => i
òóôõöø   => o
ùúûü     => u
çćč      => c
żźž      => z
śşš      => s
ñń       => n
ýŸ       => y
ł        => l
đ        => d
ß        => ss
ğ        => g
Þ        => th
ĥ        => h
ĵ        => j
```

Finally, if the above process resulted in the trailing dash, it is removed.

Comment: Only these particular substitutions? Is there not some library function which can de-adorn any Latin-ish character?

Comment: Do you describe an observation, or do you know the actual algorithm?

Comment: TIM STONE KNOWS ALL @CodeInChaos

Comment: I would have used something like `s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(c=>CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)!=UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark);` to get rid of diacritics. Which would not have handles `ß`.

Comment: See Jeff's answer in [Non US-ASCII characters dropped from full (profile) URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696), @jtbandes.

Comment: @Arjan Ah, that's more up-to-date than where I was pulling the list from, good stuff.