# Redirect loop after editing a question title ending with no-break space, question mark

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, hyperlinks, unicode

I [edited](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/10871/revisions) the title of the question [Quelle est la signification de l'expression "une fille indigne" ? Comment l'utilise-t-on au quotidien ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/10871) from the moderator dashboard. Original title:

> Une fille indigne -- Qu'est que c'est? Comment on le utilise dans le conversation quotidien?

New title:

> Une fille indigne — est-ce une allusion ?

Now the page is caught in an infinite reditect loop from `https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10871/une-fille-indigne-%e2%80%94-est-ce-une-allusion%c2%a0` to itself.

Other posts exhibit the same behavior: https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/8962/revisions, https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/10870/revisions. On the other hand, [Comment dire « go take a flying leap » en français ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9281) and [What do French tennis announcers say when the game is tied at 15 or 30 ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9804), which have similarly constructed titles but were edited earlier, are fine. It looks like titles ending with U+00A0 NO-BREAK-SPACE followed by U+003F QUESTION MARK used to be silently rewritten to U+0020 SPACE followed by U+003F QUESTION MARK, and now they are no longer mangled. It's nice not to have typographical errors silently introduced by the system, but it would be nicer if that didn't prevent the page from loading.

(Note that an unbreakable space — it should be a thin space but most people type U+00A0 or have software that does it for them — before a question mark is normal typography in France. All that English text with no space before the question mark looks weird to us.)

Comment: I rolled back the edit for now. We're looking into it.

Comment: Someone divided by zero. *Again.*

Comment: @AnnaLear Some other cases, all recent edits that added some non-ASCII character to a title: http://french.stackexchange.com/posts/8962/revisions http://french.stackexchange.com/posts/10870/revisions Questions that have had similar titles for longer seem ok, e.g. http://french.stackexchange.com/q/9281 http://french.stackexchange.com/q/9804 It may have to do with the recent examples having a proper unbreakable space before the final question mark instead of a breakable space like in the working example.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm sure that http://french.stackexchange.com/q/9804 had an unbreakable space when I edited it. It's nice that you stop silently introducing typographical errors, but it would be nicer if that didn't prevent the page from loading.

Comment: @Gilles Ah, so redirect loops *aren't* a welcome feature addition to our sites? You don't say...

Comment: This seems like it might be the same issue that we ran into at [japanese.se] two years ago: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/899/3437

Comment: Normal edits to the title break the link as well.

Comment: Gilles: you should mention that this bug was introduced today.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Actually, the underlying bug is probably at least three years old. What seems to have changed today is that some other code (the bit that converted unbreakable spaces to breakable spaces) was removed, which suddenly made the bug likely to occur on [french.se].

Comment: @Anna if it ends with a unicorn it's welcome.

Comment: It should be working now; any glitches, let me know.

Comment: @MarcGravell http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260198/redirection-error-on-question-page (did I make a mistake by editing it?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard nah, you're alright; apparently it was a trailing LTR; investigating

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks, worth checking how many other questions got it or similar unicode stuff that will cause endless redirection. (You probably got better search tools for this :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is another occurrence of web-servers and web-frameworks struggling with utf-8 encoded urls; for previous episodes, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913830/is-iis-performing-an-illegal-character-substitution-if-so-how-to-stop-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117342/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-actual-url-even-when-there-are-percent-encoded-parts). Well, it looks like it doesn't like these urls either (it comes in as though it were truncated without the whitespace/punctuation pair, hence it tries to redirect to a canonical url). We recently [enabled utf-8 urls network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214531/convert-diacritics-to-normal-letters-in-the-profile-link/233832#233832), which is why it has suddently appeared. I have disabled this again while I investigate.

Incidentally, you can't repro this on most sites: we have a flag that changes how whitespace-followed-by-punctuation is handled in question titles - and it is only enabled on language sites.

But: I have access to the low-level http request, so I'm working on a way of completely ignoring all the framework binding layers, so that we just read the raw data directly. When I have this deployed, I will re-enable the utf-8 url support.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @Braiam changes were made relating to this at the time, and UTF-8 titles are enabled everywhere (and have been for a long time). Are you seeing an issue? If so: where?